# Zookeeper server health check/monitor using python kazoo client

Tags: python, apache-zookeeper, kazoo

I have a python script to monitor the Zookeeper server health check - basically check if Zookeeper is up and running. This runs every minute.

So I have just written a simple python method which will create a new zookeeper kazoo client and then start and stop the client.

```
def __zookeeper_check(self):
        self.__logger.debug('inside the Healthcheck.__zookeeperCheck')
        try:
            zk = KazooClient(os.environ['ZOO_SERVERS'])
            zk.start()
            self.__logger.debug('Connected to Zookeeper')
            output = 0
            zk.stop()
        except Exception:
            self.__logger.error(traceback.format_exc())
            output = 1
        return output
```

Is this the right way to do it? Obviously, it's working fine in my local environment, but considering when this goes into the live production environment, it should not cause some performance issue or break anything else considering that other zookeeper clients would also be actively connected to the same Zookeeper server.

Comment: Did you get a better way to do this?

Comment: @vks No, did not get any other way. But with the above approach have not seen any issue until now